# Manipulation of list of strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.2

How A can be changed into B in python?

```
A = ['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png', 'd.png', 'e.png']
B = 'a.png;b.png;c.png;d.png;e.png'
```

Comment: `B = ';'.join(A)`

Comment: please show some effort when you ask questions here. Otherwise nobody will like you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a function called join which might come to your rescue now:

try this:

```
b = ';'.join(a)`
```

in your case:

```
A = ['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png', 'd.png', 'e.png']
B = ';'.join(A)
print b #this will return -> a.png;b.png;c.png;d.png;e.png
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple, use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> A = ['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png', 'd.png', 'e.png']
>>> B = ';'.join(A)
>>> print(B)
a.png;b.png;c.png;d.png;e.png
```